# IS there a way to determine file path while will work with irrespective of the operating system

Tags: java, filepath

I have a **maven** project with below project structure: 
**project-name** 
->**src**
---->**main**
---->**test**

Under test folder I have: 
**java**
->**com.test**
-->**inputFiles**
---->**abc.txt**

Currently I an reading above file with full path. 
something like below:

File file = new File("H:/work/project/project-name/src/test/java/com/test/inputFiles/abc.txt");  
Is there a way to avoid reading full directory path?

Comment: Put them under src/main/resources, and read them as classpath resources rather than files (i.e. using `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/test/inputFiles/abc.txt")`)

Comment: Okay, but I have to pass File object in method, not InputStream.

Comment: Then use a relative path to a file in your project (since your tests should always run from the same directory), or save the content of the stream to a temporary file (there is a standard API to create temp files), and then read that temp file.